# Can't understand error 'td-dialog' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module

everyone! I have an issue with angular modularity. Here's the issue.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/common/dialog/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'td-dialog' is not a known element:
1. If 'td-dialog' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'td-dialog' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

I don't get it why it is not a known element, since I have imported module which contains td-dialog selector (Teradata Covalent `CovalentDialogsModule`). Here's code sample of two modules: module where error occurs and root module.

```
// Module with 'td-dialog' is not a known element error
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ConfirmDialogComponent } from './dialog/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import {commonModules} from '../../app.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ConfirmDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    commonModules
  ],
  exports: []
})
export class CommonComponentsModule { }
```

```
// root module
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RootComponent} from './components/root.component';
import {appRouting} from './app.routing';
import {MainComponent} from './components/main/main/main.component';
import {MainContentComponent} from './components/main/main/main-content/main-content.component';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MainHeaderComponent } from './components/main/main/main-header/main-header.component';
import {DialogService} from './services/common/dialog.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ForbiddenComponent } from './components/forbidden/forbidden.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import {AuthService} from './services/common/auth/auth.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './services/common/auth/auth.guard';
import {AppConfig} from './app.config';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {CovalentCommonModule} from '@covalent/core/common';
import {CovalentDataTableModule} from '@covalent/core/data-table';
import {CovalentDialogsModule} from '@covalent/core/dialogs';
import {CovalentLoadingModule} from '@covalent/core/loading';
import {CovalentMenuModule} from '@covalent/core/menu';
import {CovalentMessageModule} from '@covalent/core/message';
import {CovalentNotificationsModule} from '@covalent/core/notifications';
import {CovalentVirtualScrollModule} from '@covalent/core/virtual-scroll';
import {CovalentLayoutModule} from '@covalent/core/layout';
import {CovalentStepsModule} from '@covalent/core/steps';

export const commonModules = [
  CommonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  CovalentCommonModule,
  CovalentDataTableModule,
  CovalentDialogsModule,
  CovalentLoadingModule,
  CovalentMenuModule,
  CovalentMessageModule,
  CovalentNotificationsModule,
  CovalentVirtualScrollModule,
  CovalentLayoutModule,
  CovalentStepsModule
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RootComponent,
    MainComponent,
    MainContentComponent,
    MainHeaderComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ForbiddenComponent,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    commonModules,
    appRouting
  ],
  providers: [
    DialogService,
    AuthGuard,
    AuthService,
    AppConfig
  ],
  bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As you can see I import module with 'td-dialog' selector in `CommonComponentsModule`, but can't see a place why issue can occur. Previously `commonModules` wasn't a variable with modules array, but another module only with exports, that contained all modules from `commonModules`, nevertheless error was still the same.

Was looking for a long time for an answer, but couldn't find any, I've already checked imports and tried to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to my root and submodule, but that doesn't do a trick, because `td-dialog` is an angular component.

Comment: `td-dialog` is not been imported in declarations list.

Comment: i can't find any `td-dialog` mention inside the Teradata Covalent documentation. Are you sure it exists at all?

Comment: Yes, it exists in `CovalentDialogsModule`. `td-dialog` is just extended `mat-dialog` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the error,

Please change this snippet from your code

```
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    commonModules,
    appRouting
  ],
```

to

```
    imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...commonModules,
    appRouting
  ],
```

You need to include modules from `commonModules` in the `imports`. for more you can read [about spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Same needs to be updated in your `CommonComponentsModule`

Comment: Thanks! This made a deal, I just don't get it why original snippet worked in root module, but not in submodule